# Moving one tick mark on the x-axis leftward

Tags: pgfplots

I want to move one extra tick mark on the x-axis leftward by about 2pt.  I have tried using the spacing command `\hspace*{-2pt}` before the label and `\hspace*{2pt}` after the label.  The tick mark is not moving.  I have asked a similar question and was told that the spacing command `\hspace*{}` moves the tick mark.  I have implemented it, and it did move the tick mark.  It does not move the tick mark in the following code, though.  (There are two tick marks specified.  I am only trying to move $-\sqrt[5]{6}$.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-10:10,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-1.43097,1.08447},
    extra x tick labels={$-\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 5]{6}$\hspace{10pt},$\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 5]{\frac{3}{2}}$},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-9:-0.01,blue] {x^2 + 1/(x^3)} node[anchor=west,pos=0.1,font=\footnotesize]{$y=f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0.01:9,blue] {x^2 + 1/(x^3)};
\draw [fill] (1.08447,1.96013) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] (-1.43097,1.70639) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\phantom` like in

```
$-\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 5]{6}\phantom{ab}$
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\hspace*{10pt}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-10:10,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-1.43097,1.08447},
    extra x tick labels={$-\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 5]{6}$\hspace*{10pt},$\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 5]{\frac{3}{2}}$},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-9:-0.01,blue] {x^2 + 1/(x^3)} node[anchor=west,pos=0.1,font=\footnotesize]{$y=f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0.01:9,blue] {x^2 + 1/(x^3)};
\draw [fill] (1.08447,1.96013) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] (-1.43097,1.70639) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, using `\hspace{-10pt}` before the label gives the same placement as `\hspace{10pt}` after the label. Thanks.  (Originally, I had `\hspace{10pt}` after the label just like you had, and the label was not shifted.)

Comment: Yep, its the same solution I gave you in an earlier question of yours.